# Export Windev sources

Tags: windev

I'm porting a Windev app to Objective-C for a client.
This would be simpler with the previous source code for obvious reasons.

Unfortunately, it's encrypted and I need the the EDI to see it; the full version of Windev is way to much expensive (and my client can't send me his dongle); the express version refuse to open the project because of some limitations about the project's size.

I don't need to compile the sources, so I'm looking for a way to "export" it, anything solution that allow to read the algorithm/logic of the app is OK.

Comment: Can't the client run Remote desktop or TeamViewer on his computer with the dongle connected and let you export the code that way ?

Comment: Otherwise besides using a cracked version of Windev (make sure to run it in a VM with no network access to limit the damage eventual malware can do) there aren't any solutions, there is zero documentation out there. According to [this thread](http://www.reteam.org/board/showthread.php?t=3835), disassembly won't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client can use the 'Print Documentation' from the main menu to print all the code for the project. This will print the added code for each window and procedure as well as global procedures and classes.

Answer (score 1):

From WinDev 25+ you can switch from binaray sources to text sources, then you can open the .wdw and .wdg (global procedures) and then you can export your sources.

And more, you can add your sources now to Github and make source code versioning!

[WinDev 26, project description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS6Yf.png)

Answer (score -1):

Uses teamviever or chrome desktop to uses Windev with true dongle ( tse works only if you launch windev before open tse cession)
Windev could make an dotnet to be used by c client.
Hope help you

Answer (score -1):

Porting Windev to c will be difficult :
I include C and VB into Windev for a long time.

- Database HF include in Windev had proprioatary instructions ( sql and more )
- syntax is very different
- variable attribution
  It is hard and long time job